# React: Empty element is added (perhaps because of SVG)

Tags: reactjs

I'm making Add to favorite button in React. When I click on an icon, the element beside the icon will be added to likes array. So far it's working, but sometimes empty element is added to likes array, perhaps because of SVG icon. 90% of the time, event target is 'path' so 'e.target.parentNode.parentNode.id;' works just fine. However when the event is detected on either  or , that parentNode thing won't work, and it adds an empty element to the array. How do I fix this problem?

```
class App extends React.Component {

    state = {
        data: [
            { 
                "breed": "Beagle",
                "characteristic": "playful" 
            },
            {
                "breed": "Golden Retriever", 
                "characteristic": "calm" 
            },
            {
                "breed": "Corgi", 
                "characteristic": "bright" 
            },
            {
                "breed": "Goldendoodle", 
                "characteristic": "gentle" 
            },
            {
                "breed": "Labrador Retriever", 
                "characteristic": "loyal" 
            },
        ],
        likes: []      
    }

    handleClick = e => {
        e.preventDefault();

        const breed = e.target.parentNode.parentNode.id;
        const index = this.state.likes.indexOf(breed);    

        if (index === -1) {
            this.state.likes.push(breed);
            this.renderLikes(this.state.likes);           
        } else {
            this.state.likes.splice(index, 1); 
            this.renderLikes(this.state.likes);                     
        }
    }

    likesTemplate = item => `<li>${item}</li>`;

    renderLikes = () => {
        this.refs.fav.innerHTML = this.state.likes.map(i => this.likesTemplate(i)).join('');
    }

    render() {


        return (
            <div>                
                <ul>

       {this.state.data.map(index => {
         return <li key={index.breed} id={index.breed}>
             <IcoMoon icon="heart" onClick={this.handleClick} />{index.breed}</li>;

       })}
       </ul>

       <h2>Favorite Dogs</h2>
       <ul ref="fav">

        </ul>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass a breed to your `handleClick` function.

```
handleClick = (breed, index) => {

  if (this.state.likes.filter(e => e.breed === breed.breed).length > 0) {

    this.setState({
      likes: this.state.likes.filter(e => e.breed !== breed.breed)
    });

    return;
  }

  this.setState({
    likes: [...this.state.likes, breed]
  });
};

likesTemplate = item => <li>{item.breed}</li>;

renderLikes = () => {
  return this.state.likes.map(i => this.likesTemplate(i));
};
```

Your render method

```
render() {
  return (
    <div>
      <ul>
        {this.state.data.map(item => {
          return (
            <li
              key={item.breed}
              id={item.breed}
            >
              <IcoMoon icon="heart" onClick={() => this.handleClick(item)}/>
              {item.breed}
            </li>
          );
        })}
      </ul>

      <h2>Favorite Dogs</h2>
      <ul ref="fav">{this.renderLikes()}</ul>
    </div>
  );
}
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.7.0-alpha.2/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.7.0-alpha.2/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/babel-standalone/6.21.1/babel.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>

<script type="text/babel">

class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    data: [
      {
        breed: "Beagle",
        characteristic: "playful"
      },
      {
        breed: "Golden Retriever",
        characteristic: "calm"
      },
      {
        breed: "Corgi",
        characteristic: "bright"
      },
      {
        breed: "Goldendoodle",
        characteristic: "gentle"
      },
      {
        breed: "Labrador Retriever",
        characteristic: "loyal"
      }
    ],
    likes: []
  };

    handleClick = (breed, index) => {

      if (this.state.likes.filter(e => e.breed === breed.breed).length > 0) {
        this.setState({
          likes: this.state.likes.filter(e => e.breed !== breed.breed)
        });
        
        return;
      }

      this.setState({
        likes: [...this.state.likes, breed]
      });
    };

    likesTemplate = item => <li>{item.breed}</li>;

    renderLikes = () => {
      return this.state.likes.map(i => this.likesTemplate(i));
    };

    render() {
      return (
        <div>
          <ul>
            {this.state.data.map((item, index) => {
              return (
                <li
                  key={item.breed}
                  onClick={() => this.handleClick(item, index)}
                  id={item.breed}
                >
                  <div icon="heart" />
                  {item.breed}
                </li>
              );
            })}
          </ul>

          <h2>Favorite Dogs</h2>
          <ul ref="fav">{this.renderLikes()}</ul>
        </div>
      );
    }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you! I was wondering where 'e' in 'e.breed' come from. Also, I was trying to toggle liked and unliked by clicking the icon. It seems that part has gone in the code above.

Comment: @kayak I've updated my answer to handle like and dislike.

Comment: 'handleClick = (breed, index) =>' supposed to be 'handleClick = (breed, e) =>' ?

Comment: `e` is param for `.filter()`

Comment: Got it. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Since you're already passing the breed to the list item, it'd probably be easiest for you to just pass that breed using react instead of reaching into the DOM:

```
...

    handleClick = (e, breed) => {
        e.preventDefault();

        const index = this.state.likes.indexOf(breed);    

        if (index === -1) {
            this.state.likes.push(breed);
            this.renderLikes(this.state.likes);           
        } else {
            this.state.likes.splice(index, 1); 
            this.renderLikes(this.state.likes);                     
        }
    }

    likesTemplate = item => `<li>${item}</li>`;

    renderLikes = () => {
        this.refs.fav.innerHTML = this.state.likes.map(i => this.likesTemplate(i)).join('');
    }

    render() {


        return (
            <div>                
                <ul>

       {this.state.data.map(index => {
         return <li key={index.breed} id={index.breed}>
             <IcoMoon icon="heart" onClick={(e) => this.handleClick(e, index.breed} />{index.breed}</li>;

       })}

....
```

Comment: And you wouldn't even need to pass the event. It's not clear to me what purpose `e.preventDefault()` is serving here.

Comment: and you are directly changing state value

Comment: @kayak if you don't need to `preventDefault` just do `() => handleClick(index.breed)` and remove it from params in method. Per second comment, check out [https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#do-not-modify-state-directly](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#do-not-modify-state-directly). Your solution will be to take a copy of state.likes, do your updates, then use `this.setState()` to set it again. Thanks both. P.S I'd IcoMoon the Labrador Retriever!

Comment: I deleted e.preventDefault(). I know what I'm doing is very basic but I'm already getting confused... I'll learn more about this.setState. Thank you for the link! My Icomoon goes to Golden Retriever ;)

Comment: @kayak Not at all! React is hard but it's looking awesome. I have always learned way more when I see a rough outline of what to do, "[psuedocode](https://www.wikihow.com/Write-Pseudocode)", and somewhere to start researching, so I try to provide that instead of direct answers. Keep it up!